# how to handle encoded url(contains special characters such as %2F) within the @pathvariable in springboot 2.x?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat

i have a problem about url encoding.i want to send static encoded url such as "%2FWEB-INF%2Fviews%2Fjsp%2Fhello" as a pathvariable for request in spring mvc but i can't handle this request. is anyone has suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring then initialized below bean in one of your `@Configuration` file:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
```